# Prestashop - smarty cache not generating any files - chmod set to 777 for cache and subfolders

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i am facing problem with prestashop 1.7.3. For some reason my shop on vps server is not generating any cache files. Im using a megamenu module from templatemonster and i need to cache it due hudge number of queries generated to database on each page load. I've found in google that few other shops are generating succesfuly cache for this mod under folder /cache/smarty/cache

Some dev suggested to add a cache folder to my template but that did not worked aslo.

I've set up all folders to chmod 777 (recursive). There is no php erros in logs.

Have somebody any ideas what to do?

Comment: Not sure about megamenu, but 1.7 uses the folder app/cache/dev or app/cache/prod for caching in dev mode or production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here :

Log : in app/logs
Cache : in app/cache/dev and app/cache/prod

OR

Log : in var/logs
Cache : in var/cache/dev and var/cache/prod

Regards